# Is it necessary to retrieve all the values from json object?

Tags: java, android, json

I read this article https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/  and in this article

```
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String gender = c.getString("gender");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String office = phone.getString("office");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("email", email);
                    contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

He/she has retrieved all the values before inflating it to the listview.

I am new to JSon.I tried to retrieve only names but it is not running. So, is it necessary to retrieve all the value before using any of it.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to obtain just the info you want, so a JSON object or a particular index of a JSON array.  There is no need to traverse the whole payload.  Are you getting an error message? if so, update your question with that.  If not, try tracing through with the debugger to see where it starts to go wrong.  Also it looks as though you're attempting to loop through the entire contacts array.

Comment: Listview used when you want to list many object, if you want to retrieve only one item, then retrieve it and show in a control, please add more description to your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: it depends.

When you are the one **defining** what comes in your JSON data, then you make sure to design it in a "minimalistic" way: you only want to include information that has **value** for you (or your users). Meaning: in such a world, you only transport the data that you want to display. Then, most likely, your backend code will want to access all data in your JSON strings. Because you designed all these JSON objects to hold only relevant information.

But very often, your code just consumes something. You don't own/define the JSON structure, you just know "there should be fields X, Y, Z in there, which my code will use". Then, obviously, you only extract X, Y, Z. And you leave other data in that JSON alone. There is no point in touching and processing information that isn't relevant for your use case.

In other words: in the real world, you don't do things because you *can*. You do things, because doing so results in value to you respectively to users of your product.